# Basis of the vector space of analytic functions from R to R.

Tags: vector-spaces

The set of analytic functions from R to R is a vector space over R. What will be the Hamel basis for this vector space ?

Comment: Such a basis cannot be explicitely constructed. Its existence relies on the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: I don't think there is a known basis for this. All you can get is a proof that there must be at least one, using Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: And by the way there's no such thing as "the" basis for a vector space. (Except in the pathological case of $\mathbb F_2$ as a vector space over itself).